# Amazon S3 data consistency model with object-locking mechanism

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, locking

As stated by https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Welcome.html?ConsistencyModel.html

> Amazon S3 does not support object locking for concurrent writers. If two PUT requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the latest timestamp wins. If this is an issue, you will need to build an object-locking mechanism into your application

How can we build this object-locking mechanism in Java, any hint how to start?. Unfortunately the samples in https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3

do not have any useful example in this regard.

Thanks

~M

Answer (score 4):

I would look at how Terraform is doing this, as they provide [s3-object locking mechanism](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/s3.html) for remote state files stored in S3 states. They use dynamoDB for that. The exact implementation of lock/unlock mechanism is [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/df1fc8f2c3c74c4e992a7f9690680be139bf5b0e/backend/remote-state/s3/client.go#L111).

So basically, to put an object to s3, you first have to lock it using dybamidb. This operation can be done only once due to:

```
ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exists(LockID)"),
```

Once  you successfully lock the object, you can put new one. Then you have to unlock it, also as shown in the source code.

Comment: Hello Marcin, thanks for the answer, actually I am evaluating to add Apache Ignite with ACID transactions, same approach you describe with Terraform, but maybe there is another more direct way without having to install another DB + a cache (Apache Ignite)

Comment: @MarcoTulioAvilaCerón I don't know. You can use different db/cache if you want. But dynamodb is good enough for TF, so it guess it good also for many other applications.

Comment: @mark How did it go? Still looking for "hint how to start"?